# SharePoint 2010 User Profile Picture Medium/Large thumbnail mapping the first time uploaded image.New Profile picture is not loaded

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service

I am facing the some critical issue in production server. 
I uploaded the userprofile photoA first time for USER A. Its is working fine. 
now the image stored in the User Photos/ProfilePicturs

//mysite.company.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/DOMAIN_UserName_LThumb.jpg
//mysite.company.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/DOMAIN_UserName_MThumb.jpg
//mysite.company.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/DOMAIN_UserName_SThumb.jpg

Preview Image is

http://mysite.company.com/User%20Photos/Profile%20Pictures/_w/DOMAIN_UserName_LThumb_jpg.jpg

I try to change the user profile picture for the same user. 
New Image uploaded but the old image only displayed. 
but the Preview will be new image.

if i removed the image using remove option. But all three images will be stored in the Profile picture list. Generally once the user is removed the picture then it will delete the all the relevant image in the list. In my case it won't happen .

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Hi looks like the component in sharepoint that creates the 3 versions is not working correctly. Have you looked in ULS ... also ensure you are not overwriting when you do the AD sync ( I wrote a post on some of this ) ... I notice you posted 11 months ago so it is probably solved anyway.